# Error PessimisticLockingFailureException when save data with foreign key in JPA EntityListener

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am getting the below error when saving child table data. If I will save without set Parent then works fine. Basic operation is when saving user it should also generate token through JPA EventListner.

> org.springframework.dao.PessimisticLockingFailureException: could not
> execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.PessimisticLockException: could not execute statement.

Please have a look at the below code for a better understanding of issue. Here is the parent table

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@EntityListeners({AuditingEntityListener.class, UserEventListner.class})
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    ....
}
```

Child table

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserEmailVerification {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "token")
    private String token;
}
```

And UserEventListner code is something like this

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserEventListner {

   @PostPersist
   @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
   public void onPostPersist(final User user) {
      UserEmailVerificationRepository userEmailVerificationRepository = (UserEmailVerificationRepository) BeanUtility.getBean("userEmailVerificationRepository");
      UserEmailVerification verification = new UserEmailVerification();
      verification.setUser(user); // issue is here if remove or comment it then works
      verification.setToken(Utils.generateRandomToken());
      userEmailVerificationRepository.save(verification);
   }
}
```

Comment: I think that there is an issue with a foreign key of user table; let me check it